# Как узнать, какой интерпретатор Python я использую?

Tags: python

Какой у меня установлен интерпретатор ? Пишут :

> "Если вы пишете в терминале «python», чтобы запустить интерпретатор, возможно, это CPython. Исполняемое имя для IronPython - «ipy».

и

> Если вы загрузили python по умолчанию из python.org, то это CPython.

А как точно узнать ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import platform
platform.python_implementation()
```